# How delete a pointer of classes which has pointer members?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, delete-operator

I mean, if i have some class like:

```
class A{
    int* pi;
};
*A pa;
```

when i call `delete pa`, will `pi` be deleted?

Comment: It will be if you code it to be. It won't be if you code it not to be. Decide which you want and code that.

Comment: Avoid this with standard library containers or smart pointers as members.

Comment: No. But note it will call the destructor where you can do clean up of the A instance. If you want to delete pi there then you can do that. **BUT** you must make sure you correctly own the pointer first. Loop up [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define a destructor to `delete pi;`. In addition you also need to define a copy constructor and assignment operator otherwise when an instance of `A` is copied two objects will be pointing to the same `int`, which will be deleted when one of the instances of `A` is destructed leaving the other instance of `A` with a dangling pointer.

For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    // Constructor.
    A(int a_value) : pi(new int(a_value)) {}

    // Destructor.
    ~A() { delete pi; }

    // Copy constructor.
    A(const A& a_in): pi(new int(*a_in.pi)) {}

    // Assignment operator.
    A& operator=(const A& a_in)
    {
        if (this != &a_in)
        {
            *pi = *a_in.pi;
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int* pi;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a destructor, `~A()`, that takes care of cleaning up `A`'s stuff. Afterwards, calling `delete` on a pointer of type `A` will clean-up everything.

Comment: But always remember that, if you need a destructor, you almost certainly need a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator too, per the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a destructor to delete all pointer type members. Something like:

```
class A
{
    int *pi;
  public:
    ~A(){delete pi;}
};
```

You will need to ensure that your constructor assigns a value to pi( at least a NULL). and like the answer from @hmjd, you will need to implement or hide the copy constructor and assignment operators. Look for the rule of three here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29