# Writing a destructor for a class containing a dynamically allocated array member c++

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

(C++ code)
Suppose I have a class like:

```
class A {
public: 
   int * ptr;
   int size;
    A();
    ~A();
}

A::A()
{
    ptr = new int[10];  // memory allocation is dependent upon user input into size variable 
}
A::~A()
{ 
    delete [] ptr; 
}
```

According to what I could find (sample link: [How delete a pointer of classes which has pointer members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498384/how-delete-a-pointer-of-classes-which-has-pointer-members)) this seems to be the correct way of defining the destructor here. But I tried this and it runs into run time exception. 
Even tried, `delete ptr;` but no luck

Is this the correct way of doing things?

The array based implementation of queue :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class ArrayQueue
{
public:
    int front, size, rear, curr;
    int * elem;
    ArrayQueue():size(10),rear(-1),curr(0),front(-1){}
    ArrayQueue(int n);
    void enqueue(int& e);
    void dequeue();
    bool empty()const;
    int& getFront() const;
    int& getRear() const;
    int& getSize();
    ~ArrayQueue();

};

ArrayQueue::ArrayQueue(int n)
{
    size = n;
    front = -1;
    rear=-1;
    curr=0;
    elem = new int[size];
}
ArrayQueue::~ArrayQueue()
{  cout<<"running destructor";
    delete[] elem;
}

bool ArrayQueue::empty()const
{
    return  curr==0;
}
int& ArrayQueue::getSize()
{
    return curr;
}
int& ArrayQueue::getFront()const
{
    return elem[front];
}
int& ArrayQueue::getRear()const
{
    return elem[rear];
}
void ArrayQueue::enqueue(int& e)
{
    if(getSize()==size){cout<<"Queue full"<<'\n'; return;}
    rear = ((rear+1)%size);
    elem[rear]=e;
    ++curr;
}
void ArrayQueue::dequeue()
{
    if(empty()){cout<<"Queue empty"<<'\n';return;}
    front = ((front+1)%size);
    --curr;
}


int main()
{
    ArrayQueue object;
    cout<<"Size of the queue"<<object.size<<'\n';
    cout<<"Current size:"<<object.getSize()<<'\n';
    object.dequeue();
    for(int i =0 ; i<15; i++)
    {
        object.enqueue(i);
    }
    cout<<"front element : "<<object.front<<'\n';
    cout<<"rear element : "<<object.rear<<'\n';
    cout<<"Current size:"<<object.getSize()<<'\n';
    object.dequeue();
    object.dequeue();
    object.dequeue();
    cout<<"front element : "<<object.front<<'\n';
    cout<<"rear element : "<<object.rear<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search for "Rule of 3" (Maybe "Rule of 5") and "Rule of 0". You have either too few special member-functions overridden, or too many (in the latter case, you should use a smart-pointer like `std::unique_ptr` though, no overhead, what a deal). On second thought, always use smart-pointers, whatever else you change.

Comment: Rule of three (five C++11)

Comment: The code you've presented here does not contain any errors as such. But if you ever copy objects of `A` around, you'll run into trouble (since you didn't overload the copy constructor, the default one is used and then two objects have the same pointer and it gets double-freed (and freed before it's done being used)). I suspect that's what's happening in your real code.

Comment: @Cameron In my actual code I only define a single object for the class, so there is no copying between objects. The code is for a simple array based implementation of queue.

Comment: @tinus91 post your full code then

Comment: _when_ is there a runtime exception? Are you sure it's on destruction of `ArrayQueue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the correct way of doing things?

No, not in modern C++. For example, here is one problem: if you copy the class `A` as it is, you make a so-called shallow copy and copy only the pointer. If now one of these objects goes out of scope, it deletes the array `ptr`, with the effect that the copied class can not access it anymore.

This is why there is something like the "rule of three". It states that if you need a destructor, it is likely that you handle the memory layout by yourself and therefore also require (at least) a copy constructor and an assignment operator. In your case, such a copy constructor would make a "deep copy" and set up a new array in the copied class, which contains the same elements as the array in the original class.

But all this can be avoided in modern C++.

---

The way which is considered correct there is namely to use members which manage their memory allocation itself. The most native way of doing what you intended is to use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` instead of the C-style array.

```
struct A
{
   //everything is handled correctly here without destructor, copy constructor, etc.
   //this is an example of RAII or the rule of zero 
   std::vector<int> v;
}
```

Copies, destruction and assignment is now performed by calling the corresponding copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator of `std::vector`, which you can be sure of it is implemented correctly. So, if you make a copy of your class, you create two different objects of `std::vector`.

---

Another option is to use a `std::shared_ptr`.

```
struct A
{
   std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > v;   //you could also use an int* here,
                                           //but always prefer std::vector 
}
```

Again, you don't need to care for the implementation of the copy, destructor or assignment, as you can rely on the default implementations for them.

If you make a copy of your class `A`, it is again a shallow copy, i.e. you don't copy the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr`, but only the pointer. However, now the `shared_ptr` counts the number of instances pointing to the managed `std::vector` and prevents the copied class from deleting the managed object if it goes out of scope.

---

Which of these alternatives you need depends on your requirements. In each case, you should make yourself familiar with these concepts, as in my opinion they are very important in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you don't call `ArrayQueue::ArrayQueue(int n)`, instead you call the default constructor `ArrayQueue::ArrayQueue()` in which you don't allocate memory for `elem`.